# Why does AllOf() of Hamcrest is Ok in IDEA rather than Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hamcrest

The following testing code can be compiled successfully in IDEA, while can not be compiled in Eclipse. The message from Eclipse is:

> The method allOf(Matcher<? super T>, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Matchers is not applicable for the arguments (Matcher<Object[]>, Matcher<Double[]>).

I think the type of the first argument of allOf() is inferred as Matcher<Object>, while the type of the second as Matcher<Double>. But the allOf() requires the both arguments are the same. If this is the case, why does Eclipse do its inference in this way?

```
public class HamTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Double s[] = { 23.0, 65.0 };
        assertThat(s, allOf(arrayWithSize(2), arrayContaining(lessThan(25.0), greaterThan(30.0))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse and IDEA just use your JDK compiler. Check if you're using the same version on both.

Comment: Both are used JDK8 to compile.

Comment: @m0skit0 Eclipse actually has its own compiler (ecj) which can sometimes give different messages.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I think the ECJ compiler wrongly instantiate Matcher<E[]> to Matcher<Object[]> rather than Matcher<Double[]> for the arrayWithSize(). So I modified the calling of arrayWithSize(), then the compilation passed succesfully.

```
Matchers.<Double>arrayWithSize(2)
```